# Trying to use curve_fit to fit a 3D Gaussian and getting broadcast problem (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I have spent at least 2 hours today trying to make this 3D Gaussian fitting work, but I have been unsuccessful so far! My data is in a NumPy array called "data", and data[x,y,z] gives the value of the function at the location (x, y, z) (all locations are non-negative and integer valued). I am trying to fit using a 3D Gaussian of the form:

```
# Our function gauss_3d is a function w = f(x,y,z)
# Returns the value "w" of the 3D Gaussian at point (x,y,z)
def gauss_3d(x, y, z, amplit, x0, y0, z0, sig_x, sig_y, sig_z, offset):
    sum = offset + amplit*np.exp(-(((x-x0)**2/(2*sig_x**2)) + \
            ((y-y0)**2/(2*sig_y**2) + ((z-z0)**2/(2*sig_z**2)))))
    return sum
```

My curvefitting code is as follows:

```
dim = data.shape

# Create meshgrid
XX, YY, ZZ = np.meshgrid(np.arange(dim[2]), np.arange(dim[1]), np.arange(dim[0]))

# Create data_in, which consists of (x, y, z) points. data_in has shape (392,3)
#     i.e. 392 points of the form (x, y, z), where x,y,z are non-negative integers
data_in = np.vstack((XX.ravel(),YY.ravel(),ZZ.ravel())).T

# Create data_out, which is the ravelled data. data_out has shape (392,)
data_out = data.ravel()
print(data_in)

p_param, p_cov = opt.curve_fit(gauss_3d, data_in, data_out)
print("Fitted params:")
print(p_param)
```

However, currently I am getting the error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (392,3) (392,)". I checked the documentation and it said Y and X must have the same dimension M, in my case, they both have 392 as the first dimension M=392. So why is this not working? The data_in has to have dimension (392, 3), otherwise, I can't put my (x, y, z) values in there.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://scipython.com/blog/non-linear-least-squares-fitting-of-a-two-dimensional-data/) as it actually works slightly different to what intuition would suggest.

Comment: @mikuszefski I understand my mistake now. Thank you!